# Dynamically evaluating a property string with Expressions

Tags: c#, lambda

How do I build an expression that will fulfill the following goal:

`public object Eval(object rootObj, string propertyString)`

eg: `Eval(person, "Address.ZipCode") => return person.Address.ZipCode`

Expression.PropertyOrField doesn't work because I don't have the type of each intermediate property. I'd like to avoid creating a dependency on a scripting library.

I want to try to use expressions because it would allow me to store a cache of these expression trees as they would be executed several times. I'm aware that it's possible to do this iteratively or recursively with reflection.

Comment: I'm assuming Roslyn is off the table?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```
public object Eval(object root, string propertyString)
{
    var propertyNames = propertyString.Split('.');
    foreach(var prop in propertyNames)
    {
        var property = root.GetType().GetProperty(prop);
        if (property == null)
        {
            throw new Exception(...);
        }

        root = property.GetValue(root, null);
    }

    return root;
}
```

To create an `Expression` use this:

```
public Expression Eval(object root, string propertyString)
{
    var propertyNames = propertyString.Split('.');
    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(root.GetType, "_");
    Expression property = param;
    foreach(var prop in propertyName)
    {
        property = Expression.PropertyOrField(property, prop);
    }

    return Expression.Lambda(property, param);
}
```

Comment: +1 - I was working on something just like this, but you beat me to it.

Comment: This would not work, since in the example `Person.Address.Zipcode` has root object `Person`, which does not have `Zipcode` as a property -- that is a property of the class/struct `Address`. So I think recursive evaluation is necessary.

Comment: @JohnWillemse - `root` changes on each iteration, so on the second pass, it would be looking at `Address` for `Zipcode`.

Comment: I inquired about expressions specifically. I clarified why in my edit. Thanks.

Comment: @Bobson I stand corrected! I failed to see that. `Address` must be a property though, not a field, then it will fail.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a recursive version of p.s.w.g's code, working with `Expressions`.

```
public Expression Eval(Expression expression, string property)
{
    var split = property.Split('.');
    if (split.Length == 1)
    {
        return Expression.PropertyOrField(expression, property);
    }
    else
    {
        return Eval(Expression.PropertyOrField(expression, split[0]), property.Replace(split[0] + ".", ""));
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 But I don't think you need to split the string every time if you use recursion. You can just use `property.IndexOf('.')` and `property.Substring(...)`

Comment: @p.s.w.g - Entirely true, and a better way to do it. I was just being lazy.