# IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T> Extension Fails with Foreign Key Property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sorting, iqueryable

This is the MyPageViewModel:

```
public class MyPageViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string DealerSource { get; set;}

    public override void CreateMapping()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<MyPage, MyPageViewModel>().
        ForMember(dest => dest.DealerSource,opt => opt.MapFrom(w => w.DealerSource.Value));
    }
 }
```

This is MyPage entity:

```
[Table("MyPage")]
public partial class MyPage
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid DealerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public virtual Dealer DealerSource { get; set; }
}
```

And, this is the Dealer entity:

```
[Table("Dealer")]
public partial class Dealer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } 
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Relationship between MyPage and Dealer is, Dealer can have many MyPages.

MyPageViewModel is displayed in a grid which is sortable for Id, Name and Surname columns.

This is the `OrderBy<T>` extension method for `IQueryable<T>`:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string sortProperty, ListSortDirection sortOrder)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var property = type.GetProperty(sortProperty);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
    var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
    var typeArguments = new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType };
    var methodName = sortOrder == ListSortDirection.Ascending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";
    var resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), methodName, typeArguments, source.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExp));
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);
}
```

The problem is with the `DealerSource` column. It's not possible to sort the grid by that. As it is foreign key, second line of `OrderBy` method `type.GetProperty(sortProperty)` returns `null`. I've come unstuck to find a workaround.

Comment: If `myPage` "can have many `Dealer`", why does the `DealerSource` Navigation-Property refer to single `Dealer`?

Comment: How is `OrderBy` used?  What is `T`?  If `property` is `null`, it's presumably because there is no property on `T` with that name.

Comment: Sorry. Dealer can have many MyPages. Edited the question.

Comment: @CharlesMager T is MyPage. Yes, mentally there shouldn't be any property with that name based on the truth of returning null. But we have DealerSource property in MyPageViewModel which was mapped to Dealer.Value

Comment: @Jude I'm not sure I follow.  I've copied your class definitions to prove, and `typeof(MyPage).GetProperty("DealerSource")` does not return `null`.

Comment: @CharlesMager He wants  to do `"DealerSource.Value"`

Comment: @xanatos aha! just me being dumb, then.

Comment: You can probably use something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/16545157/613130 . If you search *split property name expression* you should find plenty of examples around.